# how ONBUILD docker instruction works

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have two Dockerfile,

**Dockerfile1**

```
FROM centos:centos7
WORKDIR /root
ONBUILD COPY ./onbuilddemo.txt /tmp/onbuilddemo.txt
```

**Dockerfile2**

```
FROM onbuilddemo:latest

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jre8u352-b05-ea-ubuntu-nightly

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /root

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The image created out of dockerfile1 is **onbuilddemo:latest**
Now, when Im running the container built out of the image created from Dockerfile2 , then Im not seeing the file (onbuilddemo.txt) created/available in /tmp folder

Can someone please help , what Im missing . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You never used the `onbuilddemo:latest` image for anything, and if built with buildkit, this first step would be completely skipped:

```
FROM onbuilddemo:latest

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jre8u352-b05-ea-ubuntu-nightly
```

A multi-stage build is used to split build dependencies from the runtime image. It does not merge multiple images together (there's no way to universally do this with arbitrary Linux filesystems that would result in a lot of broken use cases).

You need to remove the second `from` step, or copy the file from the first to second stage (using `copy --from`), or add the onbuild definition to the other base image.

Note that `onbuild` tends to be a bad idea, it's hard to debug and is rarely documented in places that someone is looking to explain the behavior of their build. If you can't run the steps in an entrypoint, consider templating the Dockerfile so that it's clear exactly what's being performed in the build.

Comment: Sorry, not able to understand. when you say, You never used the "onbuilddemo:latest " image, what does it mean. ? Further, my intention is to create child / parent relationship between these images and use as inheritance to get the onbuilddemo.txt file in running container by keeping both FROM instruction. can it be possible ?

Comment: @user2315104 you defined a multi-stage build where the output of the first stage was never used anywhere else (no following step was "from" this first stage). There's no concept to add a parent to `adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jre8u352-b05-ea-ubuntu-nightly`, it has a single immutable history already. You add more history to the end of that image only, with the expose, workdir, and cmd steps.